# Can you see Pleiades and Sirius at the same time on the sky, from Greece?

Tags: amateur-observing

I would like to know if you can see the Pleiades and Sirius in the sky at the same time, from Greece?
What time of the year would that be?

And I would be very greatful if someone knows an interactive starmap where I could see how that would look like.

Comment: Stellarium is a great choice which James K pointed out. If you don't feel like downloading and installing a program, try using the online [Neave Planetarium](https://neave.com/planetarium/). It's not chocked full of all the features of Stellarium, but if you just want to see what the sky looks like at a certain time and place, that works pretty well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Stellarium](http://www.stellarium.org/) is a free planetarium software, and it allows you view the position of stars in the sky at any date.

Sirius and the Pleiades are actually rather close in the sky. On the line of Orion's belt, on opposite sides. So for much of the the winter months, both are visible in the sky. For example in mid-December, they will be visible at midnight, in south-western skies. At the time of writing (8th October) they will be visible in the early morning.

It is a well known starscape, with Orion central, the Pleiades and the V of the Hyades on one side, and Sirus, scorching on the other.

Of course, the Pleiades and Sirius are "fixed stars", so the separation between them doesn't change. There is no time when they approach each other.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they can been seen together. I have added screenshot of sky at 24th Jan 2 am IST from Sky Safari app,  [image: Sky on 24th Jan]

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is yes. Look around midnight in the South Easterly direction and you should be able to see them both at around this time of year. As James K says above, Orion is your friend.